# Select all direct descendants of an element without using a universal selector

Tags: css, css-selectors

I currently have something like this:

```
article > * { max-width: 800px; }
```

But people complain about using the universal selector. Short of manually typing each possible tag name (which I am bound to miss), what's the best way to do this without using a universal selector?

Comment: "people complain about using the universal selector" ? What does that mean ? Browser compatibility problem ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Writing_Efficient_CSS

Comment: http://twitter.github.com/recess/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can fix the width of the article, there aren't many elements that may overflow if you don't set them explicitly to a larger size. So if you set

```
article, article div, article img {
    max-width: 800px;
}
```

you're probably OK. Add one if you see one missing.

Comment: The two or three of them, yes... that means about 20 or 30 characters in your css. I never had to use `*` because when you set the size of an element, and don't set explicit random size to contained elements, there is no reason for overflow (except images).